# How to make a vscode extension that works both on node and browser

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a VS Code extension that renders a view container. According to the extension documentation, to support both Node (remote VS Code) and VS Code web, I need to include `target: 'webworker'` in my webpack.config.js file (already using webpack for bundling). Additionally, the documentation suggests adding a `"browser": "./dist/web/extension.js"` entry point in package.json.

However, I noticed a discrepancy in the documentation. While extension docs recommends using `target: 'webworker'` for both Node and the browser

According to [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/bundling-extension#configure-webpack):

> The target indicates which context your extension will run. We recommend using webworker so that your extension will work both in VS Code for web and VS Code desktop versions.

But the [examples](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/bundling-extension#run-the-extension) use the `main` entry point instead of the `browser` entry point.

My question is: should I use the `main` entry point with `target: 'webworker'` or the `browser` entry point with `target: 'webworker'` to ensure my extension runs seamlessly in both Node (remote VS) and web environments?

Already tried running in node env with webpack config. It's running fine.

Comment: "_But the examples use the main entry point instead of the browser entry point._" ... where? please quote the relevant section. I have no idea which part you're talking about, and I have a feeling you've misunderstood something somewhere